# Trouble with nil value and if statement

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm having trouble with nil values and if statements. When the variable sexualPreference is nil, the program prints "Sexual preference is not nil" and "nil". This is clearly wrong. I was wondering why is this the case? Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
databaseRef.child("users").child(user.uid).observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
    let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name:"Main", bundle:nil)

    if let sexualPreference = snapshot.value!["interestedInWomen"] {
        print("Sexual Preference is not nil")
        print(sexualPreference) 

    } else {
        print("Sexual Preference is nil")

    }

    // ...
}) { (error) in
        print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

Comment: Could you try adding `print(sexualPreference)?.dynamicType` and see what gets printed?

Comment: I added print(sexualPreference).dynamicType and it gives "nil"

Comment: he meant: `print(sexualPreference?.dynamicType)`

Comment: I tried print(sexualPreference?.dynamicType) this time and it also gives "nil"

Comment: If I go: let sexualPreference = snapshot.value!["interestedInWomen"] without the if statement and use print(sexualPreference?.dynamicType), I get "Optional(Swift.Optional<Swift.AnyObject>)"